# Como dar quebra de linha de um campo MySQL em uma página HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, quebras-de-linha

Preciso guardar um valor com uma quebra de linha na tabela

Por exemplo, ao invés de guardar:

```
0 anos, 3 dias
```

Guardar:

```
0 Anos
3 Dias
```

Tentei o seguinte processo:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (tempo) VALUES ('0 Anos\n3 Dias');
```

Ele até quebrou o código dentro do registro:

[image: http://puu.sh/h7Z1D/828fc04040.png]

Porém o resultado na página HTML foi o seguinte:

[image: Resultado]

Vou pegar esse registro numa página HTML, como faço para o valor quebrar a linha nesta página HTML? Não preciso que quebre a linha no banco de dados, desde que funcione na página em HTML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode guardar virtualmente qualquer coisa em uma coluna de caracteres. Você obviamente não pode formatar estes caracteres, eles são "puros". O que você pode fazer é colocar caracteres que indiquem formatação por alguma convenção da sua aplicação ou da linguagem que está usando. Então se quer que ele indique que deve pular linha, coloque um caractere que indique isto.

É claro que dependendo do que vai fazer para usar esse dado talvez tenha que fazer alguma coisa para a linha ser pulada, mas isto é um problema da apresentação.

Tente isto:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (nome) VALUES ('0 Anos\n3 Dias');
SELECT nome FROM tabela
```

Esse `\n` é o caractere de pular linha, dependendo de onde o use vai funcionar ou não. Outra possibilidade:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (nome) VALUES ('0 Anos
3 Dias');
SELECT nome FROM tabela
```

Se é para usar com HTML então o ideal seria isto:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (nome) VALUES ('0 Anos<br>3 Dias');
SELECT nome FROM tabela
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/Html.sql).

Mas pense bem se não tem uma outra forma de resolver isto. Há casos em que faz sentido colocar o texto de formatação junto com o texto real, mas em outro é melhor tratar isto na aplicação. Claro que você teria que ter alguma forma de indicar que existe uma separação entre esse dados. Se realmente não faz sentido ter estas duas linhas separadas em colunas diferentes, então tem que usar alguma convenção para indica a separação.

Outra possibilidade é fazer o que o Bacco falou no comentário e depois que ler o banco de dados que tem um `\n`, usa a função [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) do PHP para converter a quebra de linha de texto normal para quebra de linha de HTML.

Comment: Ele quebrou a linha perfeitamente, o problema é que o php não respeita essa quebra de linha :/ ele imprime tudo na mesma linha... Só que este é outro problema. Eu faço uma nova pergunta ou podemos prosseguir aqui?

Comment: Depende do que você está fazendo. Se for usar para por em uma página HTML é aquele primeiro caso que falei na resposta, coloca uma coisa que é convenção da linguagem HTML, ou seja, a quebra de linha é `<br>`, como o Bacco falou na resposta dele.

Comment: @Guilherme o PHP tem a função nl2br() que faz isso automaticamente (troca o CHAR(10) ou "\n" por <br> na tela). Não tinha posto na minha resposta por você nao ter mencionado PHP na pergunta. Quando for assim, tente explicar melhor os detalhes pois as respostas podem sair mais elaboradas. Tenho visto que muito das suas perguntas está sendo resolvido nos comentários, por falta de detalhes. Se puder, capriche um pouco mais na pergunta pro pessoal caprichar mais na resposta ;)

Comment: Desculpem, editei a pergunta e acho que ficou mais claro..

Comment: Com a edição funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e desculpa pelas perguntas, juro que vou tentar melhorar nas proximas :)

Answer (score 5):

Bastaria armazenar as quebras de linha:

```
 UPDATE tabela SET campo = CONCAT( "0 anos,", CHAR(10), "3 dias )
```

Notar que a quebra desejada depende de uma série de fatores:

```
 UPDATE tabela SET campo = CONCAT( "0 anos,", CHAR(13), CHAR(10), "3 dias" )
```

O mais importante é você usar corretamente os valores na hora de mostrar na tela, senão a solução não vai ser eficaz.

Tem várias outras maneiras, como simplesmente `"0 anos,<br>3 dias"` se o uso for HTML, mas para determinar a melhor saída, depende do contexto que você quer usar a quebra. Alguém poderia optar, por exemplo, por usar `"0 anos,@3 dias"` e trocar o `@` por outra coisa na tela` (mas é só mais um exemplo).

Answer (score 3):

É inviável dizer qual a solução adequada para o caso específico do autor da pergunta, mas normalmente mantém-se os dados originais no banco de dados da forma como apresentou na pergunta.

No banco de dados está salvo como "plain/text". O PHP nada tem a ver com o fato de não "quebrar a linha automaticamente no HTML", pois os dados estão em "texto plano" <sup>plain/text</sup>.

A pergunta é antiga, mas vou demonstrar outros meios para outras pessoas que possam ter a mesma dúvida e precisarem de soluções diferentes das que foram apresentadas.

## textarea

Um problema de tentar resolver substituindo no banco de dados por `<br>` é quando precisar exibir dentro de um textarea, por exemplo:

```
<?php
$str = '0 Anos\n3 Dias';
?>
<textarea><?php echo $str;?></textarea>
```

Um textarea exibirá o formato plain/text e as quebras de linha serão interpretadas.

```
<textarea>0 Anos
3 Dias</textarea>
```

Mas se o texto já vier com a tag `<br>` do banco de dados, o textarea exibirá literalmente o texto:

```
<textarea>0 Anos<br>3 Dias</textarea>
```

Se mandar imprimir fora de um textarea, na interface do browser você verá um resultado sem quebra de linha:

```
<?php
$str = '0 Anos\n3 Dias';
?>
<div><?php echo $str;?></div>
```

Resultará em `0 Anos3 Dias`, numa linha só.

Mas observe o resultado do código fonte (pressione CTRL+U no Chrome). Você verá o resultado em plain/text:

```
0 Anos
3 Dias
```

## Usando a tag `<pre>`

Pode resolver isso de diversas formas. Uma forma simples é com os próprios recursos do HTML. A tag `<pre>`, interpreta as quebras de linha (\n ou \r)

```
<?php
$str = '0 Anos\n3 Dias';
?>
<pre><?php echo $str;?></pre>
```

O resultado visual do browser será esse, mesmo sem a tag `<br>`:

```
0 Anos
3 Dias
```

## Convertendo com JavaScript

Caso queira converter as quebras de linha em `<br>`, pode economizar processos no lado server (PHP), usando JavaScript para converter.

Recomendo uma função do [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br/):

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
  var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br ' + '/>' : '<br>' // Adjust comment to avoid issue on phpjs.org display

  return (str + '')
    .replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2')
}
```

O uso é idêntico a função [nl2br()](http://php.net/nl2br) do PHP.

## Interpretando com CSS

Esteja ciente de que o funcionamento depende da versão do browser:

```
<style>
 p {
 white-space: pre;
 }
</style>
<p><?php echo '0 Anos\n3 Dias';?></p>
```

Consulte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space