# Como faço para converter dados de um campo Text com várias linhas do MySQL para HTML com quebra de linha?

Tags: html, mysql

Tenho um campo Text chamado **INFORMACOES** em minha tabela MySQL contendo dados em várias linhas:
José, 
Maria, 
Melissa,

Quando converto em HTML o resultado aparece em uma única linha:
José, Maria, Melissa,

Eu tentei incluir a tag **< br>** no final de cada linha usando um SELECT, mas não obtive sucesso.

Eu testei:

> SELECT INFORMACOES FROM minha_tabela WHERE REPLACE(INFORMACOES,'\r\n','< br>');

Como resultado obtive 34 linhas alteradas, mas eu não entendo esse resultado, porque minha tabela contém mais de 2.000 registros, e todos os registros possem mais de três linhas no campo `INFORMACOES`.

Tem uma pergunta semelhante em [Como dar quebra de linha de um campo MySQL em uma página HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57732/como-dar-quebra-de-linha-de-um-campo-mysql-em-uma-p%C3%A1gina-html) mas lá ensina como inserir os dados com quebra de linha na tabela MySQL. Eu não quero inserir, quero extraí-los da tabela para uma página HTML com uma quebra para cada linha, que estão todas no mesmo campo.

Como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 2):

Use a função **[nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php)** no resultado da consulta. Exemplo:

```
<?=nl2br($row['informacoes'])?>
```

Irá adicionar uma tag `<br />` nas quebras de linhas do registro, resultando em:

```
José, <br />
Maria, <br />
Melissa,
```

O problema é que é criado um espaço antes do `<br />`, que você pode eliminá-los com `str_replace`:

```
<?=str_replace(" ", "", nl2br($row['informacoes']))?>
```

Resultando em:

```
José,<br />
Maria,<br />
Melissa,
```

Isso se em cada linha só houver 1 nome (sem espaços).

Se houver possibilidade de 2 nomes em uma linha, use `preg_replace` para eliminar apenas o espaço apenas antes do `<br />`:

```
<?=preg_replace("/,\s/", ",", nl2br($row['informacoes']))?>
```

Saída:

```
José Antônio,<br />
Maria,<br />
Melissa,
```

Comment: Eu encontrei uma solução para o meu problema: (1) Clonei minha tabela, (2) Usando um UPDATE alterei a quebra de linha '\n\r' por '< br>' na tabela clonada. (3) Converti os registros da tabela clonada em HTML, preservando a tabela original. Deu tudo certo. (4) Por fim apaguei a tabela clonada. Esse processo foi muito rápido, como eu queria. De qualquer forma obrigado por sua ajuda. Vou testar sua resposta, depois informo aqui o resultado.

Comment: Só agora encontrei tempo para testar o uso da função "nl2br, mas eu não encontrei essa função. Acho que ela é para PHP, mas eu uso Delphi. Obrigado pela dica.