# Quebra de linhas em texto vindo do banco

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Pretendo carregar para a página, o texto vindo do banco, com os parágrafos e quebra de linha, do mesmo jeito que está no banco. Abaixo vai o que já tentei:

**View.blade.php**

```
<div>
   <p class="cont">{{nl2br(e($post->descricao))}}</p>
</div>
```

**Resultado na página**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que não entendo, é o aparecimento das tags `<br />`, ao invés do efeito desejado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como dar quebra de linha de um campo MySQL em uma página HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57732/como-dar-quebra-de-linha-de-um-campo-mysql-em-uma-p%c3%a1gina-html)

Comment: Tá aparecendo o `<br>` pq vc "pediu" pro código fazer isso. veja na documentação o que o [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php) faz

Comment: @JrD, fiz do jeito que está na documentação! "nl2br(e($post->descricao))". Logo, gostaria de saber como faria, para não pedir ao código o aparecimento das tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei a solução!

No "AppServiceProvider" acrescenta o seguinte na função "boot": \Blade::setEchoFormat('nl2br(e(%s))'); Na view.blade, podes pegar os dados de forma normal: {{$post->descricao}}. Quando escrever o texto, não precisa introduzir a tag "br", basta dar enter para quebra de linha.

Outra forma também seria: Passar a seguinte função na model em questão (que no meu caso é a model Post): public function getTextHtmlAttribute(){ return nl2br(e($this->text),false);}. Na view ficaria assim: {!! $post->descricao !!}.

Answer (score 3):

Para [exibir os dados sem escape no blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data) você pode fazer com `{!! $text !!}` e pode complementar o nl2br para chegar no resultado esperado. Ficaria assim:

```
<div>
    <p class="cont">{!! nl2br(e($post->descricao)) !!}</p>
</div>
```

**Mas tome cuidado, pois isso abre brechas para ataque XSS...**

Comment: Valeu a dica @JrD! Mas achei uma outra solução, que postarei numa resposta desta pergunta.

Comment: Achei melhor passar a outra solução aqui mesmo nos comentários.

Comment: No "AppServiceProvider" acrescenta o seguinte na função "boot": \Blade::setEchoFormat('nl2br(e(%s))'); Na view.blade, podes pegar os dados de forma normal: {{$post->descricao}}. Quando escrever o texto, não precisa introduzir a tag "br", basta dar enter para quebra de linha.

Comment: Outra forma também seria: Passar a seguinte função na model em questão (que no meu caso é a model Post): public function getTextHtmlAttribute(){ return nl2br(e($this->text),false);}. Na view ficaria assim: {!! $post->descricao !!}.

Comment: Ótimo que encontrou uma solução, @Daniel! Mas seria melhor que colocasse essa solução como resposta e marcasse como aceita, para que não fique perguntas sem respostas aceitas pelo SOpt